# How much is IIS compressing content

Tags: iis, compression, gzip

I want to see the size of file that is being transferred over the wire. It's quite big (400KB) but what is the size of the file when it is compressed. The posts I have seen on the internet say the 400KB file I see in Chrome Tools is the amount over the wire but I save the file to my machine it is the same size, if I compress it to a zip file it becomes 120 KB which suggests the 400 KB is uncompressed. Unless IIS isn't compressing it but dynamic compression is on. Can anyone suggest how I can make sure whether the 400KB is before or after compression?

EDIT: I've figure out how to display size and content in Chrome and they are the same - Is this IIS not compressing or is this the size of file after compression.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing a quick test can't explain:

I have an html file with of size of `71.0 KB (72,727 bytes)`

Chrome shows `Size: 20.0 KB` in its developer tools:

Firefox shows: `Transfered: 26.85 KB, Size: 71.02 KB`

so Chrome shows the compressed size

After turning off compression in IIS:

Firefox shows: `Transfered: 71.03 KB, Size: 71.03 KB`

Chrome: `Size: 71.03 KB`

running an offline gzip.exe on the file:

`19.7 KB (20,231 bytes)`

Comment: Cheers, so I guess my next question is - if it's 400 KB and manually compressing it into a zip file reduces it to 120 KB why isn't IIS doing it. I can see dynamic compression on. Are there any other settings to be aware of. Thanks.

Comment: What kind of file/resource are you using (html,aspx,php)? Do you see a `Content-Encoding:gzip` in the response headers in Chrome tools? Do you see the same problems with a static html file?

Comment: There is no Content Encoding in the header. It's .net API (using NancyFX rather than WebAPI) that serves up json files.

Comment: @user1102550 - So it seems IIS is indeed not compressing your content. Try googling `Dynamic Compression IIS`, there are a few suggestions out there. Some people had success by reinstalling the `dynamic compression` feature.

Comment: I think the problem is NancyFx you have to add some code I think to force it to compress. Cheers for the help in troubleshooting.